# Select Statement Create Sequence Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I create a column that ranks each `ID` by the `First` and `Last Date`?

```
ID  First_Date  Last_Date   Age_Days
A   8/28/2020   12/22/2020  116
A   1/9/2019    8/12/2019   215
A   8/15/2019   8/28/2020   379
B   5/23/2017   1/9/2019    596
B   9/21/2019   3/16/2020   177
C   3/18/2020   9/29/2020   195
```

Desired Result:

```
ID  Initial_Date    Last_Date   Age_Days    New_Column
A   1/9/2019    8/12/2019       215        1
A   8/15/2019   8/28/2020       379        2
A   8/28/2020   12/22/2020      116        3
B   5/23/2017   1/9/2019        596        1
B   9/21/2019   3/16/2020       177        2
C   3/18/2020   9/29/2020       195        1
```

My example SQL Server query:

```
SELECT 
ID, First_Date, Last_Date, Age_Days
FROM Table
ORDER BY ID, First_Date, Last_Date
```

Comment: [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by first_date) as new_column
from t
order by id, first_date;
```

Your sample data has no ties on the `first_date` so there seems to be no reason to consider `last_date`.

Comment: Should be `order by first_date, last_date`: *by the First and Last Date*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select x.ID,  x.First_Date,  x.Last_Date,   x.Age_Days,
   row_number() over (partition by x.id order by first_date) as New_Column
from x
```

You may consider a rank type function if first_date duplicates